# R function combination of vectors

Tags: r

I have a vector wih 3 elements `tempo <- c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3")`

Is there a functionwhich can give me all combinations of thoses elements without repetition?
I want a result like : `tempo2 <- c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3", "VAR1 + VAR2", "VAR1 + VAR3", "VAR2 + VAR3")`

I first tried using  `expand.grid(tempo,tempo)` but it gives me "VAR1  VAR2" but also "VAR2  VAR1".

do you have an idea?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Try with `combn` `c(tempo, combn(tempo, 2, FUN = paste, collapse=" + "))`

Comment: `do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(tempo), combn, x = tempo, simplify = FALSE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on a good track

```
@library(tidyverse) 
tempo <- c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3")
```

You won't need the factors; they'll get in the way.

```
expand.grid(tempo,tempo, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  %>% 
    # Generate all the combinations, but sort them before you paste them into a string.
  mutate(Combo = map2_chr(Var1, Var2,
         ~ paste(sort(unique(c(.x, .y))), collapse = " + "))) %>% 
    # You've cut down the combinations to only those in sort-order
  pull(Combo) %>% 
    # Get rid of the duplicates
  unique

# [1] "VAR1"        "VAR1 + VAR2" "VAR1 + VAR3" "VAR2"        "VAR2 + VAR3" "VAR3"
```

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `combn`

```
c(tempo, combn(tempo, 2, FUN = paste, collapse=" + "))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a sets based solution, you can try this. You will have to adjust the loop index to stop at 2 and get rid of NULL set if you don't need it.

```
library("sets")
all_sub = NULL
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  all_sub = set_union(all_sub, set_combn(x,i))
}
```